# Entry into aspnet_Users table

Tags: asp.net, security

I need to create an entry in aspnet_Users. The user should have a userid and password.

Is

```
    aspnet_Membership_CreateUser
```

what I would need to run in order to generate this info.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute Store Procedure by itself, because encryption/hash mechanism is in the code (not inside the Store Procedure).

The easiest way to create a user it to run the build in application.

In VS2012, Select your web application, then go to Project > ASP.NET Configuration

[image]